# Understanding python syntax for lists

Tags: python

```
list = sorted(set(list))
list[:] = sorted(set(list))
list[::] = sorted(set(list))
```

I am new to Python, and the first thing I am noticing is that the syntax is concise, but non obvious.

For example, it is not clear what is going on in the three statements above. I ran them and got some results and seems like statement 1 is not updating the list, while statement 2 and statement 3 are. But, I am sure there is more going on here.

What do each of the above assignments mean?

Comment: This is absolutely a duplicated question but I forget which question it is duplicated with ... Could someone help to flag as duplicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 3 do the same (the `step` argument of a slice is optional, and both these slices use the default `step` of `1`), but they both are inherently different from 1. Slice assignment (`lst[:] = ...`) **mutates** the original object while a common assignment (`lst = ...`) rebinds the variable to a **new** object.

```
>>> lst = [3,3,2,2,1,1]
>>> id(lst)
139793325565704
>>> lst[:] = sorted(set(lst))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(lst)
139793325565704  # same object
>>> lst = sorted(set(lst))
>>> id(lst)
139793325524744  # different object
```

A point worth noting is that slice assignment can have any iterable on the rhs (for partial slices their number of elements must match the length of the slice):

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> lst[1:] = 'ab'
>>> lst
[1, 'a', 'b']
```

See some of [the slice docs](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks, any difference b/w using `[:]` vs `[::]`?

Comment: No, not to my kowledge, they both set the `step` arg to `1`.

Comment: They are exactly the same @Lazer -- Slice notation goes `obj[start:stop:step]` or `obj[start:stop]` when omitted, start and stop are implied to be the beginning and end of the sequence respectively. When `step` is omitted, it's implied to be `1`